# Passive conversion

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

In researching a question, I came across this site http://www.grammarbank.com/passives-with-modals.html and this example of active voice being converted into passive:

Active : Do you have to pay the bill before leaving the restaurant?
Passive: the bill have to be paid before leaving the restaurant?

Is this correct?  Is this an instance of BrE and AmE grammar differing?  Also, I feel that the sentence should read "Must the bill be paid before leaving the restaurant."  Is this correct?

Comment: Looks to me like they accidentally dropped the first word of the sentence: ***Does** the bill have to be paid ...* Which is fine, and far more likely than *Must ...*

Comment: To use 'must' wouldn't be *unlikely*, it would be grammatically *incorrect*. Purely in terms of grammar it could be 'does' or 'will' or 'would'.  However  'does' is the only auxiliary verb that answers the question correctly.

Comment: @StoneyB Chasley says that using "must" is grammatically incorrect.  If I use must I would say "Must the bill be paid before..."  This is ok...right?  In one there is an infinitive and in the other there isn't one.

Comment: P.S. I see I missed the point about 'must'. I thought you were advocating, " **Must** the bill **have to be** paid before leaving the restaurant?".  I see now that in fact the suggestion was,  "**Must** the bill **be** paid before leaving the restaurant?"  That would be correct.  Apologies.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK all good, I'm a bit sloppy this morning.  A good question is why the "to" disappears in the must version.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Because *must* is a *modal verb* and modal verbs all take the 'bare' infinitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typographical error. You can tell that because the sentence begins with a lowercase letter, so obviously the first word is missing.

The correct sentence (in all varieties of English) is:

*Does the bill have to be paid before leaving the restaurant?*

Comment: Ok.  See my comments above...

Comment: A full conversion would include the agent (by you), but that doesn't work because 'you' is not meant literally.